# how do I list each record from and sqlite table as a button in my android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, view

I'm trying to list each record in a sqlite database as a button in my android app.  I'm planning on creating a cursor and calling up each record in a while loop.  this is logically where I would place the code to generate a button that serves an intent(etc.. irrelevant) for each of the records.  Once i started this I realized that I've only learned how to create views by directly coding them into my .xml files.  as the information is being called from a database, it would be impractical to have the buttons made in advance.  they need to be created when the application is opened.  any pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.  (I promise to pay it forward).

Answer (score 1):

How are you laying out the buttons ? 
You can display the buttons in a custom list view. Create a xml that has the layout of each row ( in your case just a button ) and then at runtime you can set the text ,listeners and any other properties for each button.

-Salil

Answer (score 0):

Building on Salil's answer, you might want to use a ListView backed by a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).

See [this example of SimpleCursorAdapter in ListViews](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List3.html)

Let me know if you need more details - I don't have my source code handy at the moment.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello